# Why is my if statement interpreting a boolean backwards

Tags: zsh

I am really confused on how the output of a couple of functions in my .zshrc.

```
function __isred {
  if [[ $(ps cax | grep redshift | wc -l) > 0 ]]
  then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

function __togred {
  if __isred
  then
    killall redshift
  else
    redshift &
  fi
}
```

The idea with __isred is that if redshift is running, it will return true, and false otherwise. I can confirm it returns the correct output using echos. However, when output is 1, the if statement in the __togred goes to the else block instead of the then. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For shell commands, a 0 exit status means true/success, and anything else means false/failure (with the exact value being used to discriminate between different types of failures). Best here would be to avoid using exact exit status values in the first place and use the `false` or `true` commands instead:

```
__isred() {
  if [[ $(ps cax | grep redshift | wc -l) > 0 ]]
  then
    true
  else
    false
  fi
}
```

At which point, you're starting to realise it's a bit silly, as you can just do:

```
__isred() [[ $(ps cax | grep redshift | wc -l) > 0 ]]
```

Note that `[[ > ]]` is for lexical comparison. It would make more sense to use numerical comparison here:

```
__isred() (( $(ps cax | grep redshift | wc -l) > 0 ))
```

But actually, there's no need to count the number of occurrences if you just want to check that there has been at  least one:

```
__isred() { ps cax | grep -q redshift; }
```

Should be enough. `grep` will return success if the regex is matched.

Now, while you're at using non-standard `ps` syntax, you may want to use the slightly more portable `pgrep` command instead to do that  `ps`+`grep` more easily and reliably:

```
__isred() { pgrep redshift > /dev/null; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From `zsh` manual:

```
if list then list [ elif list then list ] ... [ else list ] fi    
    The if list is executed, and if it returns a zero exit status, the then list is executed.
    Otherwise, the elif list is executed and if its status is zero, the then list is executed.
    If each elif list returns nonzero status, the else list is executed.
```

On a unix system, by convention, a return value of 0 represent success. This is counter-intuitive, but makes sense because this allows commands to use different return values for different errors.